# Django Messages working only after manual page refresh when I try display error about existing user

Tags: python, django

In my Django project I want to use Django Message ( from django.contrib import messages) to display error when user or email exist.

Unfortunately my views not working.

HTML:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def account_signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nick = request.POST['nick']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user_model = get_user_model()
        if user_model.objects.filter(username__iexact=nick).exists():
            messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
            return render(request, "account/account_signup.html", context={'is_taken_email': email, 'messages': messages})

        if user_model.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
            messages.warning(request, 'Please correct the error below.')
            return render(request, "account/account_signup.html", context={'is_taken_email': email, 'messages': messages})

        user = User.objects.create_user(username=nick, email=email, password=password)
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse(status=202)
    else:
        """Return template with sign up page."""
        return render(request, "account/account_signup.html")
```

I cant find a reason. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages" to your "context_processors" list?

Comment: Yes, I added it.

Comment: Make sure you enabled the messages correctly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages including adding the message module to INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include `messages` to context. Change your code to this:

```
return render(request, "account/account_signup.html", context={'is_taken_email': email})
```

When you pass it explicit, you override builtin variable.

Comment: Ok, I''ll check it, thanks for your answer and time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX if you are willing to refresh page after a certain update or something. 
Here is a basic example for using AJAX with Django : https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/ajaxify-django-forms/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it.